# Compute this expression using the binomial theorem: $ \sum_{i=0}^{27} \binom{27}{i} (-3)^{2i+1}$

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> Use the binomial theorem to compute:
>   $$ \sum_{i=0}^{27} \binom{27}{i} (-3)^{2i+1}$$

This is how far I got:

$$ (x+1)^{27} = \sum_{i=0}^{27} \binom{27}{i} x^i\\
-3 \cdot (-3)^{2i} = (-3)^{2i+1}\\
-3 \sum_{i=0}^{27} \binom{27}{i} (-3)^{2i}$$

I'm stuck here and don't know what to do next; could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you write $(-3)^{2i}$ in a way that makes the exponent be $i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{27} \binom{27}{i} (\color{blue}{-3})^{\color{blue}2i}= \sum_{i=0}^{27} \binom{27}{i} (\color{blue}9)^{i}=(1+9)^{27}=10^{27}$$